# vcpkg: how to install packages per project (not user-wide)?

Tags: c++, package-managers, vcpkg

Having watched the [vcpkg tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRnjahwxZ8A), reviewed the [instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) (and [integration instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/integration.md)), I couldn't find a way to:

1. Privately install a package, meaning only for use of current project, rather than user-wide
2. Derived from previous bullet - a way to install different versions of a package for different projects: if I update a package in use by project `A`, I don't want project `B` to get affected.

I assume the above wish-list is obvious, so I assume there is a way to do it...

But how? Google brought nothing.

Comment: Did you also read the [faq](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/about/faq.md#i-cant-use-user-wide-integration-can-i-use-a-per-project-integration)?

Comment: @rustyx I read it, and it's not very clear. What does NuGet have to do with vcpkg? Why isn't it simple?